# Need a guidance to understand a few lines of knockout js code

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I was reading a article from this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667422/Populate-dropdown-using-jQuery-and-KnockOut) about how to populate a dropdown using KnockoutJS. so here is the code.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountries" runat="server" data-bind="options: 
     countryModel.countries, optionsValue: 'CountryID', optionsText: 'CountryName', 
    optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></asp:DropDownList>

<input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click: addCountry" />
```

here is the JS code to bind UI.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function DropDownModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.countries = ko.observableArray();
            self.addCountry = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "DropDownSolution.aspx/GetCountries",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        self.countries(data.d);
                    }
                });
            };
        }
        var countryModel = new DropDownModel()
        ko.applyBindings(countryModel);
    </script>
```

and server side page method code which is returning data.

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Country> GetCountries()
{
     List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();
     countries.Add(new Country { CountryID = "1", CountryName = "India" });
     countries.Add(new Country { CountryID = "2", CountryName = "Singapore" });
     countries.Add(new Country { CountryID = "3", CountryName = "Malaysia" });
     return countries;
}
```

My question is when user clicks on button to add data to the dropdown list, then how does the js code understand which viewmodel function "addCountry" to call?

```
<input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click: addCountry" />
```

Because i may have many viewmodels in the same page and all viewmodels may have a function called `addCountry()`. So in that situation how does KnockoutJS understand which addCountry function of which viewmodel to call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `ko.applyBindings(viewModel)` you specify which view model that you are using.

If you specify a second argument as a DOM node (`ko.applyBindings(viewModel, someElement)`), then it will use that element as the root for your bindings, so that view model would be in effect.

So, how you apply bindings determines which view model is used for an element.  You should not apply bindings multiple times to the same elements.

Comment: just tell me can i bind button in this way <input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click: countryModel.addCountry" /> where i specify the viewmodel name like countryModel. looking for suggestion. thanks

Comment: if `countryModel` is a global variable, then you could bind against it this way.